# How to turn off bundling in Moonboots?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, ampersand.js

I'm poking at a pre-existing Nodejs app that uses Moonboots/Express, and I need to turn off bundling (via browserify) in dev. I've stripped out everything that isn't absolutely required so there shouldn't be anything funky going on, `developmentMode` is false, and fwiw `browserify.debug` is true. My interpretation of the docs (https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/moonboots) is that `developmentMode` forces recompilation on each request and doesn't minify, but still bundles the js files into one gargantuan file. (How gargantuan? This app's apparently got 57,000 lines of code.)

Dealing with this massive file makes debugging difficult, particularly as the files appear to get bundled in a slightly different order each request so any breakpoints I set are useless. I would really like to prevent the bundling from happening altogether. I've a bad feeling I'm out of luck on this, can anyone shed some light?